# Unexpected CFBundleExecutable key

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, cocoapods, ios9, xcode7-beta5

After spending some time googling, something tells me that the issue is new.

We had a fully functional project supporting iOS7-8. Of course it was multiple times successfully submitted to AppStore.

We use pods, lots of tracking and monitoring, like GA and Instabug.

Now we decided to submit a version of the app built on Xcode 7 on iOS 9 to TestFlight.

We disabled bitcode, since many pods, like Flurry and other prebuilt libraries does not include it.

The build was successful, after the submission to iTunesConnect we get this:
[image]

We had same for GoogleAppIndexing library (in pods too), but we removed it, just to make it work. Now - Instabug. It is going too far, so I am trying to understand what is going on in iOS 9 and what are the changes that made a fully working project to start throwing such errors.

Any thoughts and ideas are welcomed! Please share your experience, and if I missed something, I will gladly share my steps.

Comment: Have you solved this problem? I'm facing this issue too, but it's GoogleMaps.bundle...

Comment: No, not yet. Looks like it's a generic problem.

Comment: This is really annoying :(, I've asked on the Apple Developer forum, see if somebody else got this problem. https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/42851#42851

Comment: We're seeing this too in a new integration with Startapp. Also iOS 9 and Xcode 7 beta 5.

Comment: Moataz from Instabug here. Can you replace the Instabug.bundle that you have with this one https://www.dropbox.com/s/37zwhaqzatfnz3n/Instabug.bundle.zip?dl=0, let me know how it goes

Comment: @MoatazSoliman it worked... I got new errors, but I didn't get the Instabug bundle fail like i would expect. Please share your knowledge on this.

Comment: Here's the new link to the Instabug.bundle (https://www.dropbox.com/s/zzs7q2eygfa6wms/Instabug.bundle.zip?dl=0)

Comment: I have this problem with Google App Indexing and Google+ library. May be more such errors, I don't know. My configuration is pretty much fit yours, we're using pods, and I disabled bitcode as well.

Comment: Apple Developer Forums... I've seen tumbleweeds there the size of which you wouldn't believe!

Comment: @Johnny you link is broken

Comment: Had this in an app this week. Now I have to fix in some of our libs too. It's an Apple bug, in Xcode old versions, that they've decided to fix - but screw developers at the same time. There is NOTHING wrong with libs, but Apple changed the rules, and instead of making Xcode auto-fix the bug from old Xcode versions, they blame developers. Please: put blame where it's due - on Apple. Ask library devs to help - but it's not their fault!

Comment: This should automate your archiving : http://stackoverflow.com/a/38229037/1722474

Answer (score 114, accepted):

I encountered the same problem today with the same exact error message when trying to submit our app (using Xcode 7 beta 5) but instead of the `instabug.bundle` bit, it was for me `TencentOpenApi_IOS_Bundle.bundle`.

I solved the problem by finding the named bundle in the project then - just as the error message suggests - edited the `Info.plist` that is in the bundle by removing the `CFBundleExecutable` key. The `CFBundlePackageType` key was already set to `BNDL` so I didn't touch it.

After these changes I did Product > Clean and then had no problem submitting the app to the App store.

Comment: thank you for sharing your experience! So it IS the library author problem. But we, developers, should not do these tricks... For example, I use pods and a CI system. I cannot go to the CI and each time after pod install do this manual change. But at least we will have it working. So far I am looking for a generic solution. If it doesn't come soon, your I will mark your answer as the one that helps. Thank you again!

Comment: I can't do this. If I'm trying openning info.plist inside pod in Xcode, it told me that file locked and changes won't be save (and it doesn't). If I use external text editor, I can see that content of plist file somehow encoded, it's not a plain text.

Comment: @MikeKeskinov, could this link be helpful: [http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/68646/how-do-i-unlock-a-plist-file-so-that-i-can-change-it] ? It suggests finding the info.plist in the Finder and editing the file's permissions to allow you to edit it in Xcode.

Comment: I too had similar issue and reported to Apple.  Your steps are absolutely correct as suggested by Apple. https://bugreport.apple.com/problem/viewproblem

Comment: I wrote a shell script to remove this as a workaround. You add this as a run script during the Build Phases of your project: https://gist.github.com/brightredchilli/ca63430518f0daa4dfa9

Comment: You can script this with `PlistBuddy`: `/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Delete CFBundleExecutable" BananaKit.framework/Resources/NMABundle.bundle/Info.plist` (note that if you put this in a script, it will fail if the key is already deleted—append `|| echo "Already deleted."` to avoid this.

Comment: Thank!! you!! but Important: Don´t edit anything in the info.plist of the main target, only inside of the specific bundle!

Answer (score 53):

Encountered this with `AviarySDK` on Xcode 7 GM, while submitting to the App Store.

First I'd check to see whether you're on the latest version of your library - the vendor may have fixed this already. If you are still facing this problem however, as Sleiman describes you need to remove the `CFBundleExecutable` key from the plist file for the offending library.

Cmd + Shift + O and type "Info.plist", you can then find the appropriate file:

[image]

Once editing the plist, you may be seeing descriptive names (instead of the `CFBundleExecutable` and other keys. I couldn't edit this file in an external editor, so I had to switch to view raw keys/values by right-clicking on the list:

[image]

You can now see the `CFBundleExecutable` key (which has a description of "Executable file") which you can delete.

For AviarySDK I did this twice, once for each `Info.plist` seen in the above image, and was then able to successfully submit.

Comment: Do you know what the side effects of this are? I am having this same issue with the Polljoy bundle. Do you think that entry is just in the plist erroneously?

Comment: ["Xcode automatically adds this key to the information property list file of appropriate projects."](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001431-101909) I'm sorry I can't tell you the side effects, however I suspect it's due to using an older library that hasn't been distributed with support for Frameworks, and then Xcode tries to treat it the same as one that _does_ have support for Frameworks.

Comment: Unfortunately for some libraries (i.e. AppIndexing etc) the plist file content seems to be encripted. It allow you to view but doesn't save any changes. When tryting open file outside XCode, it's clear that file is encrypted (no plain text).

Comment: this worked for google signin, and allowed me to upload to App store

Comment: I just enountered the same issue with Aviary and Cocoapods 0.39. Your suggested fix seems to work. Looks like it might be time to bite the bullet and switch to AdobeCreativeSDK :(

Comment: What could be the reason for this issue? @AdamS

Answer (score 11):

I solve this problem as follows:
We have to remove all the "Executable files" of the following packages:

- GooglePlus.bundle
- GPPCommonSharedResources.bundle
- GPPShareboxSharedResources.bundle

Be sure that "Bundle type code" is equal BNDL

Important: Do not edit anything in the info.plist the main project.

Attached screens as they should be his "info.plist" listed above each package.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Here's what worked for me

1. Apple-Shift-F, search for CFBundleExecutable
2. Click each one except "PODS" or your main target
3. Delete it (delete key)

[image]

Answer (score 5):

If the build is submitted through **Less than(<) Xcode 7.0** then it will be submitted and also
I have solved it by following way for **Xcode 7**:

Searched for `info.plist` in the projects Project Navigator as like following image:

[image]

Now opened these `info.plist` files one by one and deleted the `BundleExecutable` key **EXCEPT the target's `info.plist`**

Now cleaned the project and achieved and It is submitted with No issue.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue in Google Maps Library i removed `CFBundleExecutable` key inside `GMSCoreResources.bundle` (`Info.plist`) which is SDK's info.plist clean project and upload to appstore.

Happy Programming.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

a simple answer to this is just disable `CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED` in the Podfile. and all working fine.

here is the code

```
post_install do |installer|
    react_native_post_install(installer)
    
    
    #############
      installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
            
        ### Added for Maps
        if target.name == 'RCT-Folly'
          target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS'] = "$(inherited) ${PODS_ROOT}/fmt/include"
            config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED'] = 'NO'
          end
        end
        #### Added For Maps Ended 

        if target.respond_to?(:product_type) and target.product_type == "com.apple.product-type.bundle"
          target.build_configurations.each do |config|
              config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED'] = 'NO'
              config.build_settings["DEVELOPMENT_TEAM"] = "XXXW7BNX6K" 
          end
        end
      end
    ############


    installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]"] = "arm64"
      config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED'] = 'NO'
      config.build_settings["ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH"] = "YES"
    end
    #__apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround(installer)
  
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Just check your Build Settings => Enable Bitcode, and set it NO

Answer (score 1):

In my case I just Drag and Drop The `SDK` In folder include `info.plist` file which is not in use. That's create the issue for me. So find the unused `info.plist` file and delete it from the Source code.

Answer (score 0):

One additional note: sometimes if you have additional targets there will be target properties that may also include the key (in the "Info" section), so make sure to check those and remove it from there also. I discovered this with one of the bundles I was trying to include. I deleted the info from the plist, but kept getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

If you're seeing this error from a library installed via CocoaPods, try a `pod update <OFFENDING POD NAME>`

That solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

I just added word "BNDL" to appropriate place in `plist` "Bundle creator OS Type code".

[image: That was the issue]