# GooglePlus Integration Issue

Tags: ios, iphone, google-plus, xcode7

[image]

I'm uploading my app over AppStore (Version 7.1 (7B91b)) with `Deployment Target = iOS8.0` but having this error at time of validation. Can anyone guide me about this issue? I'm using Google+ login in my app and looks like some issue with G+ libraries integration.

The application works fine with Adhoc builds and on simulator, only issue is when archiving for AppStore.

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32096130/unexpected-cfbundleexecutable-key it helps you

Comment: If you changed the bundle id?

Comment: Thanks  .. it solved the problem.