# Unexpected CFBundleExecutable Key. The bundle at Aviary SDK Resources.bundle

Tags: ios, xcode

I have following error when trying to upload an AppStore.

**Unexpected CFBundleExecutable Key. The bundle at Aviary SDK Resources.bundle does not contain a bundle executable. If this bundle intentionally does not contain an executable, consider removing the CFBundleExecutable key from its Info.plist and using a CFBundlePackageType of BNDL. If this bundle is part of a third-party framework, consider contacting the developer of the framework for an update to address this issue.**

a) tried to remove BNDL from plist but noting happens.

How i can fix it ?

Comment: see this link may be helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32096130/unexpected-cfbundleexecutable-key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove CFBundleExecutable key. but please do not touch main Info.plist file of the project. only change in Aviary SDK Info.plist