# Unable to submit iOS app due to Unexpected CFBundleExecutable Key

Tags: ios, xcode

On the app I'm working on, an issue was encountered when submitting the app to store:

> We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for
>   "Application X". To process your delivery, the following issues must
>   be corrected: Unexpected CFBundleExecutable Key - The bundle at
>   '/Payload/(location of resources.bundle)/Info.plist'
>   does not contain a bundle executable. If this bundle intentionally
>   does not contain an executable, consider removing the
>   CFBundleExecutable key from its Info.plist and using a
>   CFBundlePackageType of BNDL. If this bundle is part of a third-party
>   framework, consider contacting the developer of the framework for an
>   update to address this issue. Once these issues have been corrected,
>   you can then redeliver the corrected binary.

No changes has been done on info.plist and CFBundleExecutable/Executable File actually has an empty string. What has caused this error?

Also, will simply removing the CFBundleExecutable key from the plist resolve the issue?

Comment: So the bundle in question is evidently not your app; what is it?

Comment: Please check if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32096130/unexpected-cfbundleexecutable-key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explicitly removing the CFBundleExecutable key in the plist fixed the problem.