# Getting issue in email after upload app on itunes connect, Unexpected CFBundleExecutable Key

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect

Unexpected `CFBundleExecutable` Key - The bundle at **/Payload/ABCD.app/Base.lproj/Info.plist' does not contain a bundle executable. If this bundle intentionally does not contain an executable, consider removing the `CFBundleExecutable` key from its Info.plist and using a `CFBundlePackageType` of BNDL. If this bundle is part of a third-party framework, consider contacting the developer of the framework for an update to address this issue.

Comment: try solutions provided here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32096130/unexpected-cfbundleexecutable-key

Comment: Thanks for comment, I already tried solution from this link.

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer to this question: Actually accidently info.plist file was moved to some other folder.
I changed the location of info.plist to ProjectName/ProjectName/info.plist, error removed and app become eligible for submission.

I posted this answer because it may save someone time.