# iOS build is displayed as invalid at iTunesConnect

Tags: ios

iOS build is displayed invalid at iTunesConnect and Apple replies back with the following email:

> Dear developer,
>
> We have discovered one or more issues with your recent
>   delivery for "Appname". To process your delivery, the following issues
>   must be corrected: Unexpected CFBundleExecutable Key - The bundle at
>   '/Payload/Appname.app/Desktop/Appname/Info.plist' does not contain a
>   bundle executable. If this bundle intentionally does not contain an
>   executable, consider removing the CFBundleExecutable key from its
>   Info.plist and using a CFBundlePackageType of BNDL. If this bundle is
>   part of a third-party framework, consider contacting the developer of
>   the framework for an update to address this issue. Once these issues
>   have been corrected, you can then redeliver the corrected binary.
>
> Regards, The App Store team

I have tried many solution's but it can't solve my issue. Please suggest if anyone has solution to this problem.

Why is my executable not included in the app bundle?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unexpected CFBundleExecutable key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32096130/unexpected-cfbundleexecutable-key)

Answer (score 0):

If your project contain multiple .plist file then just search "CFBundleExecutable" in your project by presing command+shilf+f and remove all then CFBundleExecutable key from all .plist file except your project .plist file

Comment: I have already do it, but nothing in results ,is this problem occurs b'cos of plist file's issue??

Comment: Yes I had also face the same problem