# The bundle at 'my_app.app/ResearchKit/ResearchKit/Info.plist' does not contain a bundle executable

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, info.plist, researchkit

**Update**
XCode Version: 8.2
iOS Target: 9

Hopefully some can point out to me that this is not a bug. Very simply I pulled the latest stable version of researckKit, and I dropped the .xcodeproj file into my new iOS project, added the embedded binary. I created a couple steps that look fine in the simulator. My app builds fine and even the archive validates OK. Upload to app store is fine, but then I am receiving emails from the app store with 6 entries all look about the same, for 6 different `Info.plist` files inside the ReserachKit framework:

> Unexpected CFBundleExecutable Key - The bundle at
>   'my_app.app/ResearchKit/ResearchKit/Info.plist' does not contain a
>   bundle executable. If this bundle intentionally does not contain an
>   executable, consider removing the CFBundleExecutable key from its
>   Info.plist and using a CFBundlePackageType of BNDL. If this bundle is
>   part of a third-party framework, consider contacting the developer of
>   the framework for an update to address this issue.

I have found quite a [few answers on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32096130/unexpected-cfbundleexecutable-key), many people agreeing to do what was suggested in the error message: simply remove the CFBundleExecutable Key from the .plist files. I tried that, but then my archive will not even validate with the following error:

> iTunes Store operation failed. Invalid Bundle Structure - The binary
>   file 'my_app.app/Frameworks/ResearchKit.framework/ResearchKit' is not
>   permitted. Your app can’t contain standalone executables or libraries,
>   other than the CFBundleExecutable of supported bundles. Refer to the
>   Bundle Programming Guide at
>   https://developer.apple.com/go/?id=bundle-structure for information on
>   the iOS app bundle structure.

** UPDATE **

Granted I pulled a fresh version of the ResearchKit framework from github for this project.  So instead I just tried a copy of a version of ResearchKit from another Xcode Project that I have successfully deployed on the app store recently, i figure if it worked for that app it should go through for this app.  But Alas, I am getting the same email error from the App Store about the Unexpected CFBundleExecutable Key.

Again this is an apple-supported free framework.  There are simple instructions for how to use it on the github page, which I followed.  I have used it before and submitted an app with this framework recently, which had no problems and is currently active in Test Flight Beta Testing.  I also [filed an issue on the GitHub project page](https://github.com/ResearchKit/ResearchKit/issues/961).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted Apple Technical Support and they helped me solve the problem.  Like I had suspected it was NOT necessary to alter the ResearchKit framework in any way for this to work correctly.

For me, the issue was that I was copying the entire source code, test cases, Xcode projects, and the rest of ResearchKit into the app.

I must have done this at an early step and didn't realize.  What was helpful for me was to go to the **Build Phases** tab in XCode and look in the different sections.  My error was that I had the researchkit framework in the sections: **Link Binary With LIbraries** and **Copy Bundle Resources**.  I needed to remove those.

The correct configuration, which you get by dragging the xcodeproj file to the project and embedding the binary will just add on line to the **Target Dependencies** and **Embed frameworks** sections in **Build Phases**.

Here is a screenshot of my corrected configuration:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I met this problem like yours,and I fixed it by:

- Remove Executable file in ResearchKit
- Find info.plist in ResearchKit,do:
  delete info.plist in ResearchKit.
  Or you can add Bundle version,Bundle identifier,Bundle versions in this info.plist,they should be same as your parameters in your own info.plist
- check Target - Info - URL Types,check if there is illegal identifier