# Unable to archive project with ResearchKit but successfully works on Simulator and Device

Tags: ios, objective-c, frameworks, archive, researchkit

I have an old project which uses ResearchKit to collect survey information. The project used pod (`pod 'ResearchKit'`) and all worked fine. Now when I want to deploy this app to Testflight, Apple rejected my app saying **ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage - New apps that use UIWebView are no longer accepted. Instead, use WKWebView for improved security and reliability**. After some research, I came across some solutions suggesting to remove researchkit cocoapod and instead to use the ResearchKit project as follows https://github.com/ResearchKit/ResearchKit/issues/1346 http://blog.shazino.com/articles/dev/researchkit-setup-project/. I followed the steps exactly and was successfully able to run my app on the Simulator and also Real device. The app worked fine as before but when I tried to archive the app it gives an error saying `'ResearchKit/ResearchKit.h' file not found` 
[image]

I checked many solutions but none of them worked for me

[Undefined symbols for architecture arm64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19213782/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-arm64)

[The bundle at 'my_app.app/ResearchKit/ResearchKit/Info.plist' does not contain a bundle executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42973992/the-bundle-at-my-app-app-researchkit-researchkit-info-plist-does-not-contain-a)

Not sure if this is a bug in the library or I am doing something wrong, Request you to please help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this using pod

```
pod 'ResearchKit', :git => 'https://github.com/ResearchKit/ResearchKit.git', :branch => 'master'
```