# MicrosoftMaps, How to resolve "Unexpected CFBundleExecutable Key" error while uploading App on Appstore, with Bing map framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, bing-maps

I am using MicrosoftMaps pod in my iOS app. In the time of debug app is working fine, but when I upload this on Appstore I am getting this error.
Unexpected CFBundleExecutable Key. The bundle at 'Payload/DQT GPS.app/Frameworks/MicrosoftMaps.framework/MicrosoftMaps.bundle' does not contain a bundle executable. If this bundle intentionally does not contain an executable, consider removing the CFBundleExecutable key from its Info.plist and using a CFBundlePackageType of BNDL. If this bundle is part of a third-party framework, consider contacting the developer of the framework for an update to address this issue.

Enable disable bitcode, and try to delete CFBundleExecutable File from .plist too, and also set CFBundlePackageType of BNDL. but same problem occurs.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32096130/unexpected-cfbundleexecutable-key

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unexpected CFBundleExecutable key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32096130/unexpected-cfbundleexecutable-key)

Comment: I already go through with the this links solutions, but it doesn't help me out. Is this the problem with MicrosoftMap SDK, or any thing else. because while using this sdk i am not getting any plist for this, so how could i Remove those keys from .plist.

Comment: @PCRaykhere, there should be an ```Info.plist``` file inside the ```MicrosoftMaps.framework``` folder.

Comment: @PCRaykhere can you please confirm what is the version of the SDK that you are using?  There is a known issue with the framework that was built without full bitcode, so you may need to disable it as a workaround.

Comment: @J.PabloCandelas I am using 0.2.0 SDK version. White I enable Bitcode then my code doesn't Archive. and after disabling Bitcode I am getting this problem while uploading the build on appstore. I got the file inside the framework but this doesnt help me out, means after deleting those keys from .plist same problem occurs.

Comment: @J.PabloCandelas Will you please suggest, How I will upload my app on Appstore. I am getting this problem. and go through many solutions and links but this doesn't help in my case.

Comment: @PCRaykhere The fix for this issue and the bitcode problem will be available in our next v1 release very soon.  Thank you for reporting this.

Comment: @J.PabloCandelas, Thanks For your reply, When we expect your stable version. we are in phase to release our product.

Comment: @PCRaykhere  This issue should be fixed in the latest SDK version (v1.0.0)  that was just released.

Comment: Fixed in the new version

Answer (score 0):

This should be fixed in the latest Bing Maps SDK for iOS, version 1.0.0.
This release enables bitcode and fixes other framework issues that prevented apps from publishing to the Store.

Comment: Fixed in new version